# Http request speed and limits for updating Sharepoint list items

Tags: xmlhttprequest, sharepoint-online

I am building an interface to update a Sharepoint list of a couple thousand items with a couple hundred columns. The interface will update, two or three times a day, a couple thousand fields.

After a few different experiments, I figured that the best way would be to write a script to submit the changes via HTTP requests and I would like to understand whether there are any unforeseen limitations I should know about. I am aware that a single request can update only some 160 items (rows). Are there any limits to columns per item? Or fields per request? Requests per time?

Also, my script will send one request per changed item/row, but speed is of a certain concern. Is it better to send 2000 requests for 2000 items, or 20 requests, each with 100 items?